# use HTML tags in JS variable (react)

Tags: html, reactjs, tags

I'm trying to see wether a user was mentioned in a post. If so I want to link the user name to the profile.

What I tried:

```
  if (mentions.length === 1) {
    const splitSearch = '@' + mentions[0].user.name;
    const replaceWith =
      '<a href=profile/' +
      mentions[0].user._id +
      '>@' +
      mentions[0].user.name +
      '</a>';
    newText = text.split(splitSearch).join(replaceWith);

  }

...

return (
...
{mentions.length > 0 && (
  <p id='text-container'>{newText}</p>
)}
```

But I just get back the tags as plain text:

```
hi <a href=profile/5f1bd6c7d90cb03e845adbbf>@user1</a>. 
hello <a href=profile/5f30380288a63e001755401e>@user2</a>.
```

Do I need to write the `replaceWith` const in another way? I tried `Link` instead of `a` but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React can only render JSX components.

Rather than constructing an HTML string, construct an *array of children*. When a mention is found, put an `<a>` (a JSX element, not a string) into the array between its adjacent children:

```
const children = text.split(splitSearch);
// Insert an `<a>` between each element:
for (let i = children.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  const a = <a href={`profile/${mentions[0].user._id}`}>@{mentions[0].user.name}</a>;
  children.splice(i, 0, a);
}

// Then render:
{mentions.length > 0 && (
  <p id='text-container'>{children}</p>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have a few questions. Why do you use "children.length - 2"? If someone would type "hi @user1" that would just be 0, wouldn't it?
I tried both with and without -2. Both times I get back an empty array after splicing.

Comment: I still can't really get it to work. When I log "children" after the splicing, i have an array. So that works. But {children} is empty. Since the splicing is inside an if-statement, I need to say something like "let children = []" before that, right?

Comment: Once you've generated the children array, you need to get that to the render section somehow - whether that's by reassigning `children` or something else

Comment: it works. thanks a lot. do you know how i can map through the mentions? so is more than one user is mentioned, every user gets an a-tag?

Comment: You could use `.match` instead of `.split` - match anything that's a mention, or match anything that's not a mention, to split them apart, then use `.map` on the array to turn all mentions into `<a>`s.

Answer (score -1):

it is wrong.

Idea of react is not "generate own html like in your example".

You should use map inside return (and generate `Link` for every item in array) like this:

```
return (
    {
        mentions.length > 0 && (
            <p id='text-container'>
                {
                    mentions.map((m) => (
                       <Link key={m.user._id} to=`${m.user._id}`>
                         {m.user.name}
                       </Link>
                    ))
                }
            </p>
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: The problem with this: the mention is inside a text. For example "Hello @user1, what I wanted to tell you...". When I simply map the mentions I won't be able to just link the username, will I?